# Passing value and iterating an arraylist in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

i need to pass an arraylist to javascript from jsp and then iterate through the list in javascript. Can someone help me with the jsp synatax as well as javascript iteration code?

TIA

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.

Comment: why you want to iterate, if to show a list on the page you can use logic:iterate and jsp display tag

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("aaa");
list.add("bbbb");
list.add("cccc");
Iterator individualItems = list.iterator();
int i = 0;
String script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var list = new Array();";
while(individualItems.hasNext())
{
    script += "list["+i+"] = \""+individualItems.next()+"\";";
    i++;
}
script += "for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){document.writeln(list[i]);}";
script += "</script>";
//now do whatever you want with it
PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
output.println(script);
```